# Kinect hand waving gesture

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm doing a kinect Application using **Kinect SDK**.

The Result I want that it has to able to identify the hand waving for 5sec. Do something if it does Anyone knows how to do so?

I'm doing in a WPF application. Would like to have some example. I'm rather new to Kinect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a simple alghoritm to get the wage gesture. For your example you need a time limit

```
public static int timeLimit = 5000;
```

Now think about wave. It has 3 states

1) Neutral pose when your hand is at the same position on X-axis as your elbow.

2) When hand is to the right of elbow

3) When hand is to the left of elbow

Remember that you start from state 1. To get from 2 to 3 you need to go with 1 in the middle. So as you can see there is a combination 
1 - 2 - 1 - 3 - 1 <-- first wave

The secuence you can get from Position of Joint

```
first.Joints[JointType.HandRigh].Position.X
```

it`s simple math.

About the  sec. Just get from (for example) SkeletonFrame timestamp and compare

```
if((currentTimestamp - startTimestamp) < MainWindom.timeLimit)
```

startTimestamp is timestamp when your hand is in position to start.

Add also a flag tha indicates that the the hand is on a good track

I hope it helped

Answer (score 4):

Check the Kinect Toolbox project @ http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/. It has Swipe gesture detector implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Channel 9 Kinect for Windows Quickstarts](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart) if you need to learn the basics.

Back to the waving gesture, use math like polar coördinates to check the distance between your hand and let's say your middle shoulder and calculate the angle.

In that way you'll be able to check with previous values.
Is this clear or not really?